# Ayuda mi transaccion en php pdo se realiza algunas veces y otras no

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estoy llevando acabo una transaccion, lo que hago primero es un post de valores obtenidos de un form tanto de arrays como de variables, algunas veces se insertan los valores correctamente en la table pedidos y detalle, en otras ocaciones esto no ocurre.

```
<?php
include_once 'resource/session.php';

          if ($_SESSION['capturar_pedidos'] == 1){   

//including the database connection file
include_once("resource/Database.php");

if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {   
                $cliente = $_POST['cliente'];
        $orden_de_compra = $_POST['orden_de_compra'];



            $productos= (is_array($_POST['productos'])) ? $_POST['productos'] : array();
        $unidad= (is_array($_POST['unidad'])) ? $_POST['unidad'] : array();

            $cantidad= (is_array($_POST['cantidad'])) ? $_POST['cantidad'] : array();

            $fecha_de_embarque= (is_array($_POST['fecha_de_embarque'])) ? $_POST['fecha_de_embarque'] : array();

            $notas = (is_array($_POST['notas'])) ? $_POST['notas'] : array();
            $etiquetado= (is_array($_POST['etiquetado'])) ? $_POST['etiquetado'] : array();





    if(empty($cliente) || empty($productos) ||empty($unidad) ||empty($cantidad) || empty($fecha_de_embarque)  || empty($etiquetado) ) {

        if(empty($cliente)) {
            echo "<font color='red'>Campo cliente esta vacio.</font><br/>";
        }



        if(empty($productos)) {
            echo "<font color='red'>Campo producto esta vacio.</font><br/>";
        }

        if(empty($unidad)) {
            echo "<font color='red'>Campo unidad esta vacio.</font><br/>";
        }

        if(empty($cantidad)) {
            echo "<font color='red'>Campo cantidad esta vacio.</font><br/>";
        }

        if(empty($fecha_de_embarque)) {
            echo "<font color='red'>Fecha de embarque esta vacio.</font><br/>";
        }


        if(empty($etiquetado)) {
            echo "<font color='red'>Campo etiquetado esta vacio.</font><br/>";
        }



        //link to the previous page
        echo "<br/><a href='javascript:self.history.back();'>Regresa</a>";
    } else { 
        // if all the fields are filled (not empty) 
        try {
    /* First of all, let's begin a transaction */
                if(empty($orden_de_compra)){
                 $db->beginTransaction(); 
         $sql = "select orden_de_compra from clientes where cliente=:cliente"; 
$result = $db->prepare($sql); 
$result->bindparam(':cliente', $cliente);


$result->execute(); 
$orden_de_compra = $result->fetchColumn();  
              $arreglo = explode("-", $orden_de_compra);
                    $numero_sin_ceros =(int) $arreglo[1] + 1;

                    $numero_sin_ceros = str_pad((string)$numero_sin_ceros, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
$orden_de_compra_nuevo  = $arreglo[0] . '-'.$numero_sin_ceros ;   


    $sql = "UPDATE clientes SET orden_de_compra=:orden_de_compra_nuevo WHERE orden_de_compra =:orden_de_compra_actual";


$result = $db->prepare($sql); 
$result->bindparam(':orden_de_compra_nuevo', $orden_de_compra_nuevo);
$result->bindparam(':orden_de_compra_actual', $orden_de_compra);

$result->execute();      
    }

else{
                  $db->beginTransaction(); 


}

            //return a string of all the array elements
$string_productos = implode("[x]", $productos);
             $string_fechas = implode("[x]", $fecha_de_embarque);

             $string_unidades = implode("[x]", $unidad);
             $string_cantidades = implode("[x]", $cantidad);
             $string_notas = implode("[x]", $notas);
             $string_etiquetados = implode("[x]", $etiquetado);

$longitud_productos = strlen(utf8_decode($string_productos));
 $longitud_fechas = strlen(utf8_decode($string_fechas));
  $longitud_unidades = strlen(utf8_decode($string_unidades));
             $longitud_cantidades = strlen(utf8_decode($string_cantidades));
  $longitud_notas = strlen(utf8_decode($string_notas));
  $longitud_etiquetados = strlen(utf8_decode($string_etiquetados));

if($longitud_productos <= 255 and $longitud_fechas <= 255 and $longitud_unidades <= 255 and $longitud_cantidades <= 255 and $longitud_notas <= 255 and $longitud_etiquetados <= 255) {


}
            else{
    $string_productos = "Para ver los productos ve a la seccion detalle de pedido";
             $string_fechas = "Para ver las fechas ve a la seccion detalle de pedido";

             $string_unidades = "Para ver las unidades ve a la seccion detalle de pedido";
             $string_cantidades = "Para ver las cantidades ve a la seccion detalle de pedido";
             $string_notas = "Para ver las notas ve a la seccion detalle de pedido";
             $string_etiquetados = "Para ver los etiquetados ve a la seccion detalle de pedido";            


            }

    // A set of queries; if one fails, an exception should be thrown
   $sql = "INSERT INTO pedidos(cliente, orden_de_compra, productos, fechas, unidades, cantidades, notas, etiquetados) VALUES(:cliente, :orden_de_compra, :productos, :fechas,:unidades, :cantidades, :notas, :etiquetados)";

            $insertStmt = $db->prepare($sql);

        $insertStmt->bindparam(':cliente', $cliente, PDO::PARAM_STR);
         $insertStmt->bindparam(':orden_de_compra', $orden_de_compra, PDO::PARAM_STR);
         $insertStmt->bindparam(':productos', $string_productos, PDO::PARAM_STR);
         $insertStmt->bindparam(':fechas', $string_fechas, PDO::PARAM_STR);
         $insertStmt->bindparam(':unidades', $string_unidades, PDO::PARAM_STR);
         $insertStmt->bindparam(':cantidades', $string_cantidades, PDO::PARAM_STR);
         $insertStmt->bindparam(':notas', $string_notas, PDO::PARAM_STR);
         $insertStmt->bindparam(':etiquetados', $string_etiquetados, PDO::PARAM_STR);


$insertStmt->execute();

$sql = "INSERT INTO detalle(orden_de_compra, cliente, producto, unidad, cantidad , fecha_de_embarque, notas, etiquetado) VALUES(:orden_de_compra,:cliente, :producto, :unidad, :cantidad , :fecha_de_embarque, :notas, :etiquetado)";

$insertStmt = $db->prepare($sql);

         $i=0;
    foreach ($productos as $producto) {


        $insertStmt->execute( array('orden_de_compra' => $orden_de_compra,'cliente' => $cliente,'producto' => $producto,'unidad' => $unidad[$i],'cantidad' => $cantidad[$i] ,'fecha_de_embarque' => $fecha_de_embarque[$i] ,'notas' => $notas[$i] ,'etiquetado' => $etiquetado[$i] ));
                        $i++;





    }                  

        // Alternative to above bindparam and execute
        // $query->execute(array(':name' => $name, ':email' => $email, ':age' => $age));
    // If we arrive here, it means that no exception was thrown
    // i.e. no query has failed, and we can commit the transaction
    $db->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // An exception has been thrown
    // We must rollback the transaction
    $db->rollback();
}











                $URL="index.php";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.location.href='{$URL}';</script>";
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" content="0;URL=' . $URL . '">';


    }
}


          }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Y el resto del planteamiento del problema?

Comment: Basicamente es eso algunas veces se lleva a cabo la insercion en la base de datos otras no, asi lleve orden de compra o no

Comment: ¿No has pensando que en algunos casos podrías estar intentando un `INSERT` que cree valores duplicados y por eso falle? Si revisas el `error_log` podrías ver exactamente lo que está ocurriendo.

Comment: Bien mire dentro del error_log y no me muestra errores, eso si me encuentro con redes de internet muy inestables en este lugar

Comment: Daniel, debes revisar el `error_log` que se encuentra en la carpeta donde está el archivo php en cuestión. Si el código está fallando debe haber algo ahí. Si no, encierra el código en un bloque `try... catch...` imprimiendo por pantalla cualquier error eventual.

Comment: Me sale esto si imprimo el errorr del catch SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '' for key 'orden_de_compra'

Comment: existe un problema en el orden que estas dando intenta poniendo condicionales a tu execute ejemplo if($insertStmt->execute()){//Aqui si pasar la siguiente consulta.}

Comment: Daniel es justo lo que te dije antes: *Integrity constraint violation* indica que en ocasiones los registros que intentas insertar violan una regla de integridad... Y el *duplicate entry* indica que la regla que se está violando es la de entrada duplicada. O sea, en las inserciones que intentas hay datos con clave primaria duplicada y por eso no se insertan.

Comment: Asi es agregaba valores duplicados en aglunas ocasiones en un campo unique

Answer (score 0):

La transaccion funcionaba perfecto yo hacia el post con valores tomados de un select, este ultimo era obtenido de la base de datos y me percate de que eliminaba dobles espacios en blanco, los cuales deje por accidente al registrar algunos clientes, lo que hice fue usar en el where el id en lugar del varchar nombre del cliente:

```
  <select required name="id_cliente">
 <?php
        echo '<option value="">Selecciona un cliente</option>';

                    $sql = "Select id_cliente, cliente from clientes";

    $query = $db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
       while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<option value= "'.$row['id_cliente'].'">'.$row['cliente'].'</option>';
       }
     ?>
 </select>
```